# passing values to a function in a powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I am curious if it's possible to pass arguments to a powershell module using object notation.  Look at the following definition of a function:

```
function Get-Something
{
    Param
    (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
         [string] $Name,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
         [int] $Id
    )
}
```

can I call this function in the following notation:

```
Get-Something(Name "Vance Refrigeration", Id "9")
```

instead of doing:

```
Get-Something -Name "Vance Refrigeration" -Id 9
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only other way than to type every variable with '-Name "Vance Refrigeration" -Id 9' is to do the following:

```
function Get-Something
{
    Param
    (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
         [string] $Name,
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
         [int] $Id
    )
    Write-Host $name en $id
}
$object = @{Name = "Vance Refrigeration"; Id = "9"}
Get-Something @object
```

Or with the prettier styling for the object:

```
$object = @{
    Name = "Vance Refrigeration"
    Id = "9"
}
Get-Something @object
```